# Add custom "Booking" button to WooCommerce Product single pages

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

Having trouble with this issue, any help is appreciated!

I want each of my woocommerce single product pages to have a button "Book Now" that links to a page that I created on WordPress titled "Booking Appointments".

That "Booking Appointments" page contains a "Easy Appointment" Plug in Form (that clients will fill out) that I installed which I also want to have it auto populate the product's SKU or values into one of the form inputs (from the pervious page) so that I do not have to enter it each time.

I tried a variety of methods online but its not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

This will add in single product pages a "Book Now" button **linked to your "Booking Appointments" page** passing through the URL the product ID, the product sku…

So the code will be:

```
// Add a custom button in Single product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replacing_template_single_add_to_cart', 31, 0 );
function replacing_template_single_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $sku = $product->get_sku();

    // Set below the page ID, your button text and link parameters to pass in url
    $page_id = 124;
    $button_text = __('Book Now', 'woocommerce');
    $link = get_permalink( $page_id ) . '?id=' . $product_id . '&sku=' . $sku;

    // Output your custom text
    echo '<a href="'.$link.'" class="book-now button">'.$button_text.'</a>';

}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> In your your **"Booking Appointments" page** form you will be able to get the values from the URL with **`$_GET` to populate necessary fields** with an additional scripts in which you will use:
>
> ```
> $product_id = $_GET['id'];
> $sku = $_GET['sku'];
> ```

Tested and works in WooCommerce 3+.

Comment: I am having trouble with auto-populating the custom input forms since I am unfamiliar with this "easy appointment" plugin.. Do you know how?

Comment: The personal information is not needed to auto-populate. I just added a ProductID field (refresh and see) and I just need to get the URL parameters to fill it in automatically when the page loads. Cannot find anything online.. @LoicTheAztec

Answer (score 1):

At the very end of `content-single-product.php` you can add

```
<a class="button-link" href="<?php 
get_page_by_path(booking-appointments); 
?>">Booking Appointments</a>
```

then use .button-link to style the link to look like a button.

Comment: Tried it on the default content-single-product.php, but its still redirecting to the current page (refreshes the page)