# Auto-populate input form field from URL parameters

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I have a button on a woocommerce page (`http://.../product/abcd/`) that has a button "Book Appointments Now" that links to another page with form fields to submit (`http://.../booking-appointments/?id=1238&sku=1`) which has `ProductID` and `SKU` on the URL of that product from the previous page.

I want it to auto-populate the `ProductID` field automatically each time this page loads from the URL parameters.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To auto populate the product ID and the product SKU in your booking form (page), you should try this *(without any guaranty as it can be tested for real on your page form)*:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'autopopulate_product_id_script' );
function autopopulate_product_id_script() {
    if( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ):
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $('input[name="productid"]').val("<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>");
            $('input[name="productsku"]').val("<?php echo $_GET['sku']; ?>");
        })(jQuery);
        </script>
        <?php
    endif;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> The product id and the product sku need to be passed in url something like: `http//www.example.com/booking-page/?id=124&&sku=AH1584`

And your `<imput>` text fields should be something like:

```
<input type="text" name="productid" val="">
<input type="text" name="productsku" val="">
```

So for the product sku is something similar, that you will be able to add with ease…

> But as javascript is already very active in you "Easy Appointments" booking form, I don't know if this will work.

---

This answer is related to: [Add custom "Booking" button to WooCommerce Product single pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137236/add-custom-booking-button-to-woocommerce-product-single-pages/46138234#46138234)

Comment: Thanks again, but where do I add the <input type="text" name="productid" val=""><input type="text" name="productsku" val=""> in the files?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the product ID and SKU in the URL and get it via `$_GET`. Then load it into the input field. Here's an example:

`http://www.example.com/?product-id=123&sku=abcd456`

Then use `$_GET` to get the URL parameters:

```
$productId = $_GET['product-id'];
$sku = $_GET['sku'];
```

Your input field would be like this:

```
<label for="product-id">Product ID:</label> <input type="text" name="product-id" id="product-id" value="<?php echo $productId; ?>" disabled>
```

I even added a `disabled` attribute to prevent the user/customer from editing the product ID. You can use PHP to secure it from the backend when the form gets submitted.